Renormalization on External Sources in Effective Potential Formalism
Effective potential formalism provides an intuitive definition of stabe states in quantum field theory, see chapter 11 in Peskin and Schroeder, that is defined at the minimum of effective potential. In this formalism, we introduce the presence of external source,
$$Z[J] = \exp(-iE) = \int{\mathcal{D}\phi\exp\left(i\int{d^4x\,\mathcal{L}[\phi]}+J(x)\phi(x)\right)}.\tag{11.43}$$
When computing the high-order correction to the effective potential
$$\Gamma = E - \int{d^4x\,J\phi},\tag{11.47}$$
we would like to not only consider the counterterm in Lagrangian $\mathcal{L} + \delta\mathcal{L}$ but also the counterterm in the external field $J+\delta J$ with additional renormalization condition that the value of $\textit{classical field}$
$$\phi_{cl} = \langle\Omega|\phi|\Omega\rangle_{J}\tag{11.46}$$
remains despite of the fluctuation $\phi = \phi_{cl} + \eta$, where the contribution of $\eta$ at high-order cancelled with the contribution of $\delta J$.
My question is, the formalism manually add the external source to our Lagrangian, so does the presence of counterterm and renormalization condition of external source $J$ mean that it is physically observable?

It is a source of particles.  You certainly can see extra particles popping up.

So, what we've done here is extend the concept of $J$ introduced in the partition function $Z[J]$. Instead of setting $J$ to zero after calculating the correlation functions in the free theory, we've treated it as a physical quantity.
